# True of False: Every sequence contains a Cauchy subsequence?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, proof-verification, cauchy-sequences

For my practice midterm exam this is a question:
State whether the following are true or false AND briefly explain why (or give counterexample):

Statement: Every sequence contains a Cauchy subsequence.

I said this is false because I used the example that the sequence of{x_n} = n is divergent. Therefore a convergent subsequence cannot exist, therefor a Cauchy subsequence cannot exist since all Cauchy sequences are convergent.

Am I right or am I missing/getting mixed up some proper information?

Comment: This is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your example is fine, but not your explanation. The sequence $\bigl((-1)^n\bigr)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is also divergent, but it has Cauchy subsequences.

However, the distance between any two distinct terms of the sequence $(n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is at least $1$. That proves that it has no Cauchy subsequence.